# Charles breakpoints cause EOFException and MalformedChunkCodingException

Tags: android, okhttp, charles-proxy

I'm using Charles to intercept Web API calls from my Android application so that I can manipulate the response and test out conditions like timeouts and token expires (I get a 403 when token is expired). But I have been getting an EOFException since a while ago and I cannot figure out where the problem is. The exception looks like this,

```
05-29 18:28:12.374 W/System.err: java.io.EOFException
05-29 18:28:12.374 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.require(RealBufferedSource.java:59)
05-29 18:28:12.374 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.readHexadecimalUnsignedLong(RealBufferedSource.java:284)
05-29 18:28:12.374 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.readChunkSize(Http1Codec.java:444)
05-29 18:28:12.374 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$ChunkedSource.read(Http1Codec.java:425)
05-29 18:28:12.374 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.request(RealBufferedSource.java:66)
05-29 18:28:12.374 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:387)
05-29 18:28:12.375 W/System.err:     at okio.RealBufferedSource.rangeEquals(RealBufferedSource.java:371)
05-29 18:28:12.375 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.Util.bomAwareCharset(Util.java:412)
05-29 18:28:12.375 W/System.err:     at okhttp3.ResponseBody.string(ResponseBody.java:173)
05-29 18:28:12.375 W/System.err:     at facilit.net.core.webapi.WebApi.workOrderGetList(WebApi.java:200)
```

At first I thought it's maybe because I'm editing the response but it seems any Web API call that stops at the breakpoint causes the exception. It's the same exception always. I tried different emulators and my device. In all cases it's the exact out come.

Request code

```
@Nullable
    public WorkOrderListResultObject workOrderGetList(@Nonnull JSONObject params) throws WebApiNotInitializedException, IOException {
        if (isInitialized()) {
            final RequestBody requestBody = getRequestBody(params);
            final Request request = getRequest(NetworkConstants.GET_WORK_ORDER_LIST_URL, requestBody);

            try {
                final okhttp3.Response response = mClient.newCall(request).execute();
                final String string = response.body().string();

                final WorkOrderListResultObject workOrderListResultObject = new WorkOrderListResultObject();
                workOrderListResultObject.setResponseString(string);
                workOrderListResultObject.setStatusCode(response.code());

                return workOrderListResultObject;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                throw e;
            }
        } else {
            throwNotInitializedException();

            return null;
        }
    }

private RequestBody getRequestBody(@Nonnull JSONObject params) {
        return RequestBody.create(mediaType, params.toString());
    }

private Request getRequest(@Nonnull String url, @Nonnull RequestBody requestBody) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (url.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("url cannot be empty");
        }

        return new Request.Builder()
                .url(BuildConfig.FACILIT_SERVER_BASE_URL + url)
                .addHeader(NetworkConstants.CONSTANT_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN, FacilitApplicationContext.getFacilitApplicationContext().getAuthenticationToken())
                .addHeader(NetworkConstants.CONSTANT_MOBILE_APP_VERSION, mVersionName)
                .addHeader(NetworkConstants.CONSTANT_MOBILE_PLATFORM_ID, mMobilePlatformValue)
                .addHeader(NetworkConstants.CONSTANT_APPLICATION_ID, mApplicationIDValue)
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();
    }

public static WebApi getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new WebApi();
            mClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(TIME_OUT_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(TIME_OUT_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(TIME_OUT_MILLISECONDS, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();
        }

        return mInstance;
    }
```

If it helps any further I'm in middle of a Web API migration from traditional Apache APIs to OkHttp and old Apache APIs as well throws error...

```
org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException: Chunked stream ended unexpectedly
```

which I highly doubt is occurring due to a server setting change.

An example server response,

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 30 May 2017 05:16:38 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

After using an interceptor in OkHttp I noticed the following difference,
If not stopped at the breakpoint:

```
Received response for http://webapitest.demo.net/api/workOrder/getList in 1979.3ms
                             Cache-Control: no-cache
                             Pragma: no-cache
                             Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
                             Expires: -1
                             Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
                             X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
                             X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
                             Date: Tue, 30 May 2017 12:45:41 GMT
                             Content-Length: 23461
                             Proxy-Connection: Keep-alive
```

If stopped:

```
Received response for http://webapitest.demo.net/api/workOrder/getList in 8169.2ms
                             Cache-Control: no-cache
                             Pragma: no-cache
                             Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
                             Expires: -1
                             Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
                             X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
                             X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
                             Date: Tue, 30 May 2017 12:46:36 GMT
                             Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                             Proxy-Connection: Keep-alive
```

Comment: Probably the app relies on a steady connection and you're halting the connection between the endpoint and your app.

Comment: Can you show us your request code?

Comment: @moritzg how do you mean? This was working fine and suddenly started happening. Could a change in server side cause this? And I just left office tired after trying to figure this out whole evening. I'll paste some code as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @moritzg I have edited the question with request code. And thanks to who ever down voted without a given reason.

Comment: Thank you, it really seems that you have a kind of stream to your server (`Chunked stream`) it seems. So there's not a kind of Request/Response connection you can halt. It relies on a persistent connection and when you stop that connection you get your EOFException. What I would do now is trying to replicate the API call with for example `Postman` and see if it makes a difference. What you could try too is to use `mitmproxy` instead of Charles.

Comment: Just tried with Postman. Breakpoints work as expected. Also I see the response as well. If I'm understanding you correctly Postman should also be throwing a similar error right?

Comment: We were just narrowing down the problem. It lies in your Android App code, because if Postman works, there's nothing wrong with your server. Are you able to see the requests in other apps?

Comment: Yep. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Maybe your app or your phone doesn't like to connect to Charles. If you see  the requests of other apps, then you can make sure Charles works correctly. You could try using another method of making the request to see if that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145426/discussion-between-janithar-and-moritzg).

Comment: Turns out this was an issue cause by Charles.

Comment: I thought so, how did you find out?

Comment: After noticing the response header difference using the OkHttp interceptor, it was obvious Charles was causing the header changes and I checked and confirmed the lack of 'Content-Length: 23461' in the response header received by OkHttp was the cause of the EOFException. Doing any changes to the API was not an option and I'm quite sure I did not do settings changes to Charles as well. So I tried to use mitmproxy but that was too complicated, so I started using ZAP. It serves the purpose of Charles and IMO even better. ZAP is free so I didn't even bother about Charles afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After noticing the response header difference using the OkHttp interceptor, it was obvious Charles was causing the header changes and I checked and confirmed the lack of 'Content-Length: 23461' in the response header received by OkHttp was the cause of the EOFException. Doing any changes to the API was not an option and I'm quite sure I did not do settings changes to Charles as well. So I tried to use mitmproxy but that was too complicated, so I started using ZAP. It serves the purpose of Charles and IMO even better. ZAP is free so I didn't even bother about Charles afterwards.